# Hello! a beginner with C++ Programming& I need help

Tags: c++

[image: When I build the solution]

Okay! I really need your help or some tips
I need a program that I will recieve a raise on my previous years salary. I need to calculate and display the amount of annual raises for the next three years. I want to use the rates o 3% 4% 5% and 6%.

This is what I have so far but its not working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int beginSalary  = 0;
    double newSalary = 0.0;
    double raise     = 0.0;
    double theRate = 0.0;

    cout << "Beginning Salary (negative number or 0 to end): ";
    cin >> beginSalary;

 do 
 {

        // 3 percent
        newSalary = (beginSalary+(beginSalary*3/100)); 
        raise = newSalary-beginSalary; 
        cout << raise << endl; 
        cout << endl;


        // 4 percent
        newSalary = (beginSalary+(beginSalary*4/100)); 
        raise = newSalary-beginSalary; 
        cout << raise << endl;


        // 5 percent
        newSalary = (beginSalary+(beginSalary*5/100)); 
        raise = newSalary-beginSalary;  
        cout << raise << endl; 
        cout << endl;

        // 6 percent
        newSalary = (beginSalary+(beginSalary*6/100)); 
        raise = newSalary-beginSalary; 
        cout << raise << endl; 
        cout << endl;

    } while ( newSalary != 0);

    return 0;
}   //end of main function
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What output do you expect, compared to the output you're getting?

Comment: You should not erase your question after you get the answer. Besides, it doesn't work, actually. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5499786/revisions.

Comment: Please don't just delete a question after others have spent their time helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
int beginSalary;
do {
    cout << "Beginning Salary (negative number or 0 to end): ";
    cin >> beginSalary;
    if (beginSalary <= 0) break;

    for (int percent = 3; percent <= 6; percent++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Raise for " << percent << "% for the next three years: " << endl;
        double salary = beginSalary;
        for (int year = 1; year <= 3; year++)
        {
            double raise = salary * percent / 100.0;
            salary += raise;
            cout << "Year " << year << ": " << raise << ". ";
        }
    }
} while (1);
```

Answer (score 0):

cin >> ...
should be inside the loop. or you'd have an endless loop.
or a different loop condition would be better

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the input request:

you have to move the CIN instruction inside your loop.
The loops repeat only the part inside the block {}.

The while condition need to be changed too, because with **!= 0** you won't ask again on negative value (as stated in the cout sentence)

```
   cout << "Beginning Salary (negative number or 0 to end): ";

 do 
 {
    cin >> beginSalary;

//A LOT OF CODE
} while ( newSalary <= 0);
```